# How to set cookie-secure directly in weblogic server instead of giving weblogic.xml?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

we have to set cookie-secure directly in weblogic server instead of giving weblogic.xml

```
<session-descriptor>
<cookie-http-only>true</cookie-http-only>
<cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to have http-only cookies as a default. This is not possible in WebLogic. You could try to add a custom filter class, but you would have to insert this into every web.xml which is just as much of a hassle.

The better option would be to configure this in a web server or layer 7 load balancer that proxies traffic to WebLogic. For a crude example, insert the following in an Apache virtual host config to add the HttpOnly and Secure flags to every set cookie.

```
Header edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HttpOnly; Secure"
```